# TextView not visible in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I followed how to create tabs in the `Action Bar` using `Fragment`s in Android from this [site](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/761642-android-app-development-for-beginners-navigation-with-tabs). While the tabs turned out fine, the `TextView` that's supposed to appear in the middle of the `Fragment`s is nowhere to be seen. I've looked at other StackOverflow questions that relate to this but none solved my problem.

**FragmentTab1.java:**

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment {
    final String TAG = "FRAGMENT_TAB_1";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab, container, false);
        TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtvwTab);
        textview.setText("one");

        Log.i(TAG, "textview's text: " + textview.getText());

        return view;
    }
}
```

The strangest thing about this is that, while the `TextView` is not visible, when I look at the `LogCat`, it still says "*textview's text: one*". Clearly, the `TextView` is still getting created. There are no error messages at all.

**tab.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtvwTab" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" //added later
        android:textColor="@color/Black" //added later
        android:textSize="40sp" //added later
        android:alpha="1" //added later
        android:text="DEFAULT" //added later
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the original code, I couldn't see the "*one*" displayed, so I tried editing the `XML` file. I tried changing where it's displayed. I tried specifying its color, its text size, its alpha, and even its default text. Nothing worked!

So what am I still missing? Why is the `TextView` clearly present and is getting its text set while not actually being visible?

**EDIT (more code):**

**Main.java:**

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    ActionBar.Tab tab1, tab2, tab3;

    Fragment fragmentTab1 = new FragmentTab1();
    Fragment fragmentTab2 = new FragmentTab2();
    Fragment fragmentTab3 = new FragmentTab3();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Remove status bar
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        // Hide the status bar.
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("1");
        tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("2");
        tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("3");

        tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab1));
        tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));
        tab3.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab3));

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(tab3);
    }
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.novoloc.upup2.Main" />
```

**TabListener.java:**

```
public class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    Fragment fragment;

    public TabListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // nothing done here
    }
}
```

Comment: hey one small try, instead of `RelativeLayout` try out `LinearLayout` and set `orientation` to `vertical` and see the results :-/

Comment: No luck with that either. :(

Comment: it must be the problem f height and/or width.  set a background color for the relative layout and then set a contrasting color for textview and see if they are drawn. also try setting a solid height and width in `dp` and see

Comment: I've tried to make the width = 300dp and height = 150 dp. I've also made the RelativeLayout be explicitly white. Still no luck with either. :(

Comment: What is the value of @color/Black?  I wonder if whatever color this maps to is the same as your background color?

Comment: That's thinking outside the box! ;) Unfortunately, that's not it. Within `colors.xml`, `White` is `#FFFFFF` and `Black` is `#000000`.

Comment: show us the part of code where u r instanting the fragment and how u r adding it

Comment: Ok! I've added some more code where everything else is called.

Comment: try this.Log.i(TAG, "textview's text: " + textview.getText().toString());

Comment: Yep! With or without `.toString()`, it still outputs `one` in the `LogCat`.

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the similar problem. But i have figured out that the textview is there but it is hiding under the extended toolbar/actionbar(because of including the tablayout in it). Give your textview a margintop of 100dp or 200dp and give it a background color and you will be able to see that it is there but hidden under the actionBar. Or you can even contract the ActionBar by sliding on it upward to reveal your textview.

See the question below for how to solve this :
[Fragment from View Pager hiding behind Tab Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319928/fragment-from-view-pager-hiding-behind-tab-bar)

Answer (score 0):

Been having a headache over this, finally found a simple solution. Set your **ViewPager** height to an absolute value instead of `android:layout_height="match_parent"` or `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

> Try `android:layout_height="300dp` or some preferred value.