# Fragment from View Pager hiding behind Tab Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs, android-recyclerview

I am having an issue with a Tab bar and ViewPager in my android project. What the app does it has an activity which hosts a tab layout and then has 2 fragment which represents each of the tabs.

When the activity is opened it posts to an API to get some data and puts the data into a data adapter for a Recycler View and Card layout in each of the fragments.

The recycler view will contain 3 items but only 2 are being shown as  the first is being hidden under the toolbar and/or the tab bar as shown in the screenshot below.

Below is the layout file of my activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.BoardiesITSolution.CritiMonApp.AppsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <!--app:layout_behaviour="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behaviour" />-->
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Below is the layout of the fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <view
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the layout for card layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:elevation="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtApplicationName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="#222"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Below is the screenshot as mentioned above which shows the problem. I've pixelated some of the text but it should you what I mean, there should be 3 items but the first item is hiding underneath the tab bar.

[image: Screenshot showing the issue]

Comment: In my case, the Recycler View was appearing over the Tabs. The below solution helped me too.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Edit**: As suggested below by @smeet and @hardik, adding the scroll behavior `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` should fix the problem while preserving the scroll behavior. **Scroll behaviors only work if the view is a direct child of the coordinator layout.**

---

**Old Answer**

Just Wrap your appbar layout and viewpager in a vertical LinearLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.BoardiesITSolution.CritiMonApp.AppsActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        //appbar layout

        //viewpager    


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

From the docs, `CoordinatorLayout is a super-powered FrameLayout`. So you can expect the typical "lay views on top of other views" FrameLayout behavior.

Answer (score 15):

Adding :

> app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

in `ViewPager` resolved issue in my case.

Comment: @this should be accepted answer because if we will wrap appbar layout with linear layout than toolbar will not hide when you scroll.

Comment: Excellent, it seems to be the simplest way to do it

Answer (score 4):

**if we will wrap app bar layout with linear layout than toolbar will not hide when you scroll so accepted answer might not help you if you want to hide toolbar when you scroll.**

**Smeet did it right way** but not explained! here is full example with explanation.

add **`app`** namspace to CoordinatorLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
......
>
```

and just add below line in your `ViewPager`

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

complete xml will be as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```