# TextView hiding behind Tabs Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I've implemented a tab layout in my app. And have created 3 fragments for each tab. All fragments contain a single `TextView` and it is a child of `NestedScrollView`. Everything works as expected until the string passed to the `TextView` is large enough and needs to be scrolled for viewing it completely. At that time, the text inside `TextView` hides behind the tabs.

I've tried the answers provided here: [Fragment from View Pager hiding behind Tab Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319928/fragment-from-view-pager-hiding-behind-tab-bar?answertab=active#tab-top)
to no avail.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PrayerActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BuddhaPoojapathMarathi.AppBarOverlay">

        <!--<TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />-->

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here's one of the fragments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Fragment_1">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frag1_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:paddingTop="48dp"
        android:text="@string/buddha_vandana_mar" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

[image]

As seen in the image the first part of the text is hiding behind the tabs.

**Update:**

`PrayerActivity.java`

```
public class PrayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityPrayerBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int num = getIntent().getIntExtra("num", 0);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("num", num);

        Log.d("myInt", String.valueOf(num));
        binding = ActivityPrayerBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), num);
        ViewPager viewPager = binding.viewPager;
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = binding.tabs;
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your code in activity

Comment: Does it scrollable?

Comment: Yes @TicherhazFreePalestine, it is scrollable.

Comment: May I know why are you using `CoordinatorLayout` ?

Comment: It's a default layout that comes with the new tabbed activity in android studio.

Comment: do you try to make android:layout_height="wrap_content" for CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: @M.G, I tried it, but even that didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `RelativeLayout` instead `CoordinatorLayout`. First, Change the layout to `RelativeLayout`. Second, add attribute `id` to the `AppBarLayout`. Last, add attribute `layout_below` to `ViewPager`. You can see at below. I did not test the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PrayerActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.BuddhaPoojapathMarathi.AppBarOverlay">

    <!--<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />-->



    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't work! I edited the code as you have suggested, but still facing the same problem.

Comment: @VishalA. I have updated the answer. I added `Toolbar`

Comment: This is how it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/WF6xX39

Comment: @VishalA. can you try it againg new updated answer

Comment: It isn't working dude. The XML you are seeing is a ```MainActivity```. ANd the ```TextView``` is in the ```Fragment``` which has got its different XML.  Now, I am not able to use the size occupied by these tabs in the fragment XML. If I could do that, my problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

just put this line in NestedScrollView

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back_btn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_26sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_26sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/back_arrow"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back_btn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:text="@string/my_listing_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_1sdp"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray"/>

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"/>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: I am doing some changes please try